# Testing Error : ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, integration-testing

I am learning automated testing with Selenium in Python.

I am trying to test a web project, there is a creating page, I wrote a test file and it looks like correct because it is mostly getting successful when the test file is run but the same file with same code is sometime failing (one every two runs)

What is the problem?

---

Code:

```py
import unittest
from unittestcase import TestRE
from common_functions import AddProperty
from locators import CommonPageLocators, SigninPageLocators, AddPropertyPageLocators
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import property_values as pv
import HtmlTestRunner
import time

class TestAddNewProperty01(TestRE):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.add_property = AddProperty(self.driver)
        self.signout = AddProperty(self.driver)
        self.add_property.signin(SigninPageLocators.EMAIL_INPUT, SigninPageLocators.PASSWORD_INPUT, SigninPageLocators.LOGIN_BUTTON)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_add_new_property_01(self):
        self.add_property.add_property_button(AddPropertyPageLocators.ADD_PROPERTY_BUTTON)

        self.add_property.prop_name(AddPropertyPageLocators.PROPERTY_NAME, 'AddNewP01')
        self.add_property.prop_address(AddPropertyPageLocators.PROPERTY_ADDRESS, pv.address)
        self.add_property.investment_inflation(AddPropertyPageLocators.INVESTMENT_INFLATION, pv.investment_inflation_amount)
        self.add_property.investment_inflation_currency(AddPropertyPageLocators.INVESTMENT_INFLATION_CURRENCY, pv.investment_inflation_currency)
        self.add_property.repatriation_inflation(AddPropertyPageLocators.REPATRIATION_INFLATION, pv.repatriation_inflation_amount)
        self.add_property.repatriation_inflation_currency(AddPropertyPageLocators.REPATRIATION_INFLATION_CURRENCY, pv.repatriation_inflation_currency)
        self.add_property.analysis_start_date(AddPropertyPageLocators.ANALYSIS_START_DATE, pv.analysis_start_date)
        self.add_property.general_partner(AddPropertyPageLocators.GENERAL_PARTNER, pv.general_partner)
        
        self.add_property.default_rentable_space_designation(AddPropertyPageLocators.DEFAULT_RENTABLE_SPACE_DESIGNATION, pv.default_rentable_space_designation_type)
        self.add_property.identifier(AddPropertyPageLocators.IDENTIFIER)
        self.add_property.rentable(AddPropertyPageLocators.RENTABLE, pv.rentable_area)
        
        self.add_property.market_gross_rental_rate(AddPropertyPageLocators.MARKET_GROSS_RENTAL_RATE, pv.market_gross_rental_rate_amount)
        self.add_property.long_term_market_vacancy_rate(AddPropertyPageLocators.LONG_TERM_MARKET_VACANCY_RATE, pv.long_term_market_vacancy_rate_percent)
        self.add_property.overall_property_cap_rate(AddPropertyPageLocators.OVERALL_PROPERTY_CAP_RATE, pv.overall_property_cap_rate_percent)
        self.add_property.expected_inflation_rate(AddPropertyPageLocators.EXPECTED_INFLATION_RATE, pv.expected_inflation_rate_percent)
        self.add_property.landlord_discount_rate(AddPropertyPageLocators.LANDLORD_DISCOUNT_RATE, pv.landlord_discount_rate_percent)
        
        self.add_property.full_market_value(AddPropertyPageLocators.FULL_MARKET_VALUE, pv.full_market_value_amount)
        self.add_property.currency_symbols(AddPropertyPageLocators.CURRENCY_SYMBOLS, AddPropertyPageLocators.CURRENCY_SYMBOL)
        self.add_property.purchase_price(AddPropertyPageLocators.PURCHASE_PRICE, pv.purchase_price_amount)
        self.add_property.loan_to_value(AddPropertyPageLocators.LOAN_TO_VALUE, pv.loan_to_value_amount)
        self.add_property.interest_rate(AddPropertyPageLocators.INTEREST_RATE, pv.interest_rate)
        
        # self.add_property.operating_expenses(AddPropertyPageLocators.OE_NONCONT_TYPE, pv.oe_noncont_type_text, AddPropertyPageLocators.OE_NONCONT_RATE, pv.oe_noncont_rate_amount, AddPropertyPageLocators.OE_NONCONT_YOY, pv.oe_noncont_yoy_percent)
        # self.add_property.isCAM(AddPropertyPageLocators.OE_NONCONT_isCAM_input)
        
        self.add_property.improvements(AddPropertyPageLocators.IMPROVEMENT_TYPE, pv.improvement_type, AddPropertyPageLocators.IMPROVEMENT_COST, pv.improvement_cost)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.add_property.leasing_commissions(AddPropertyPageLocators.NEW_LEASE_RATE_PERCENT, pv.new_lease_rate_percent)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.add_property.leasing_commissions(AddPropertyPageLocators.RENEWAL_EXTENSION_RATE_PERCENT, pv.renewal_extension_percent)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.add_property.leasing_commission_methods(AddPropertyPageLocators.NEW_LEASE_METHOD, AddPropertyPageLocators.NL_METHOD_NET)
        time.sleep(3)
        self.add_property.leasing_commission_methods(AddPropertyPageLocators.RENEWAL_EXTENSION_METHOD, AddPropertyPageLocators.RE_METHOD_NET)
        
        self.add_property.click(AddPropertyPageLocators.SAVE_BUTTON)
        self.add_property.assert_elem_text(CommonPageLocators.HEADER_PAGE_NAME, 'Create Property') # final assertion1
        # self.add_property.assert_elem_text(CommonPageLocators.FINAL_FIRST_PROPERTY, 'AddNewP01') # final assertion2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='/home/khan/Projects/Automation Tests/REAuthomation/retop/results/html_pages/addnew'))
```

---

Error message:

```
Unittest Results
Start Time: 2020-11-08 22:45:46

Duration: 25.76 s

Summary: Total: 1, Pass: 0, Error: 1

__main__.TestAddNewProperty01   Status  
test_add_new_property_01    
Error
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1195, 913). Other element would receive the click:

...
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
Traceback (most recent call last): File "TCADDNEWP01.py", line 60, in test_add_new_property_01 self.add_property.leasing_commission_methods(AddPropertyPageLocators.RENEWAL_EXTENSION_METHOD, AddPropertyPageLocators.RE_METHOD_NET) File "/home/khan/Projects/Automation Tests/REAuthomation/retop/common_functions.py", line 215, in leasing_commission_methods WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(method_locator)).click() File "/home/khan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT) File "/home/khan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute return self._parent.execute(command, params) File "/home/khan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "/home/khan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (1195, 913). Other element would receive the click:

...
(Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
Total: 1, Pass: 0, Error: 1 -- Duration: 25.76 s
```

Comment: You might have an overlapping element which gets the click instead.

Comment: I foresee you've used Sleeps which is not a best practise. You mus try and use selenium waits to ensure even if the page takes longer time to load then the script waits till page loads completely (or control becomes interactable)

Comment: @arundeep , that's the point which i've to try to solve.

Comment: @Mrunal , it is not the main problem, i wrote time.sleep to try to see the transaction in slowmotion.

Comment: Is there no another solution?

Comment: There's a driver.execute_script() where you target the element with a click.

Comment: @KhanKhan In my view I would  suggest you run the test in debug mode and check in DOM as well as on browser (visually) just before the click on the desired control what is the control which is hiding / overlapping on it. Post which you can add a expected condition wait for that control to disappear and then click.